# Load data to form using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load data from a Service to a form but is not binding to the field value the data loaded from the service/server:

The data from service is coming OK, the problem is after setting here in this code, I load a route to my form but the form keeps with the old values, this code is in my controller:

```
$scope.cadastro = {
    email: '',
    name: 'the name to put in the field',
    city: ''
};

$scope.editar = function () {
    myAppServices.getUserData($rootScope.uid).then(function (data) {
        if (data !== null) {
            $scope.cadastro = data;
            $scope.cadastro.name = data.name;
            $location.path('cadastro');
        }
    });

};
```

the HTML form:

```
<form name="myDataForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label no-padding-right" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-model="cadastro.email" focus/>
                <span ng-show="myDataForm.email.$error.email" class="help-inline">Email is not valid</span> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label no-padding-right" for="name">Nome Completo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" ng-model="cadastro.name" />
                <small class="errorMessage" data-ng-show="myDataForm.name.$dirty && myDataForm.name.$error.required"> Informe seu nome completo.</small>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label no-padding-right" for="address">Cidade</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cidade" ng-model="cadastro.city" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="lbl col-sm-5"> </span>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <button type="submit" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="salvarcadastroForm(cadastro)" data-ng-disabled="myDataForm.$invalid">
                <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What should I do?

**SOLUTION:
Load user data in a init method in the controller:**

```
$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.reset();

    // if user logged then load data
    if ($rootScope.uid !== undefined) {
        myAppServices.getUserData($rootScope.uid).then(function (data) {
            if (data !== null) {
                $scope.formData = data;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible for you create a plunkr or a fiddle? Although not the source of the problem, this line seems redundant. $scope.cadastro.name = data.name;

Comment: When you do `$location.path('cadastro');` it will load new controller instance. Need to bind that data to a service object if you want it to persist

Comment: Any example how could I bind that data to a service object?

Comment: A route param would actually probably make more sense.  Then load the data in controller based on routeparam, not before you switch location